# django model formset update only

Tags: django, forms

I want to use ModelFormset to update table data. Each row on picture contains one form with two fields, and one field in form required.

[image]

I don't want to use empty form to create new object and can just remove it from rendering in template, and subclass save method to save only forms with initial data from queryset:

```
class MyFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

def save(self, commit=True):
    if not commit:
        self.saved_forms = []
    return self.save_existing_objects(commit)
```

but empty form still need to be validated, and i got validation error on required field.

How can i disable using/validating of "new object" form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/) parameter

The number of empty forms that is displayed is controlled by the extra parameter. By default, formset_factory() defines one extra form; the following example will display no blank forms:

```
  modelformset_factory(model, formset=MyFormSet, extra=1)
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help